# C++ - iterator for a vector of objects not compiling

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std, operator-precedence

I have a class Tree and I'm trying to iterate through a list of them and print the `data` member of that class, I have the following two methods in the class:

`Node` definition within `Tree`:

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
};
```

Snippet of the `writeSets` method:

```
void Tree::writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &list, Node const* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Displays all preceding left values
    for (std::vector<Node const*>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it->data;
        *** Getting compile error here **
    }
}
```

**Compile error is:**
: error: request for member 'data' in '* it. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> with _Iterator = const Tree::Node**, _Container = std::vector >', which is of non-class type 'const Tree::Node*'

`data` within the `Node` object is of type `Int`, not sure if I need to define the expected datatype of the iterator as well as the datatype that the vector is wrapping to overcome this error.

Would appreciate someones help here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write `(*it)->data`.

`*it->data` is equivalent to `*(it->data)`.

Comment: timrau - many thanks for your quick response, that's fixed it. Alex